# ASP.NET Core MVC: how to bind entities to a specific user using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I know my question is kinda broad but I haven't found any good answers online.

I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC web app. I am looking for tips on how to bind a specific user to entities (classes in model). The problem is really about how to bind a certain user to a certain entity in the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use different action methods if your business logic is limited. or use something like factory method that accept parameter depend on user type/name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you mean you want to build the relationship between User table and other table?If that is the case, you could refer the [Relationships](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key), [One-to-Many Relationship Conventions in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx) and [Customize Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0)(if you are using Asp.net core Identity)

Comment: Add a UserId to the relevant entity

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationUser` (or `IdentityUser`) is like any other entity class.

Creating a 1-n relationship, for example, would look something like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual IList<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; } // navigation property
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }        // FK
    public ApplicationUser CreatedByUser { get; set; } // Navigation property
}
```

You could also do this the fluent way:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser { }
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<MyEntity>(b => {
            b.HasOne<ApplicationUser>()
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(myEntity => myEntity.CreatedByUser);
        });
    }
}
```